# How to add keystore to react native app to use firebase auth?

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I am developing react native app I am trying to use firebase authentication with otp code from sms and it is work with ios, but not with android. In android I have such error
[image: error from firebase]
I try to solve this issue like it is described [here](https://rnfirebase.io/)
I ran `./gradlew signingReport` from android folder and found that I have error `Error: Missing keystore` 
[image: screen from terminal]
Does anyone know how to solve this? Thanks!